# How to Connect Two Box2D Libgdx Bodies Together (Body and a Head)

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, box2d

I have a rendered animated boy and I have a rendered animated head. They both use Box2d bodies and they are both circle shapes. My question is how do I combine the two together so that I have a head on top of a body. Currently the body can move around and I just need to figure out how to attach the head on top of it. Any help is appreciated. I also tried joints but I couldn't figure out which joint would work, the distance joint wasn't working.

[This image shows how my game currently looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Etb.png)

This is my class for the body:

```
public class isaac extends Sprite {
    public enum  State { WALKINGY, WALKINGX, STANDING,  };
    public State currentState;
    public State previousState;
    public World world;
    public Body b2Body;
    private TextureRegion isaacStand;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> isaacWalkX;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> isaacWalkY;
    private float stateTimer;
    private boolean walkingRight;
    private boolean walkingDown;
    public Body b2Head;

public isaac(World world, playScreen screen){
    super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("isaac_body"));
    this.world = world;

    currentState = State.STANDING;
    previousState = State.STANDING;
    stateTimer = 0;
    walkingRight = true;
    walkingDown = true;

    Array<TextureRegion> frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    for(int i = 6; i < 8; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i*32, 0, 32, 32));
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i*32, 32, 32, 32));
    isaacWalkY = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.1f,frames);
    frames.clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 64, 32, 32));
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 96, 32, 32));
    isaacWalkX = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.1f, frames);

    isaacStand = new TextureRegion(getTexture(), 0,32, 32, 32);

    defineIsaac();
    setBounds(0,0,28 / icsGame.PPM, 28 / icsGame.PPM);
    setRegion(isaacStand);
}

public void update(float dt){

    setPosition(b2Body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2Body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
    setRegion(getFrame(dt));

}

public TextureRegion getFrame(float dt){
    currentState = getState();

    TextureRegion region;
    switch(currentState){
        case WALKINGY:
            region = isaacWalkY.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
            break;
        case WALKINGX:
            region = isaacWalkX.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
            break;
        case STANDING:
        default:
            region = isaacStand;
            break;
    }

    if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0 || !walkingRight) && !region.isFlipX()){
        region.flip(true, false);
        walkingRight = false;
    }
    else if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x > 0 || walkingRight) && region.isFlipX()){
        region.flip(true, false);
        walkingRight = true;
    }

    if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y > 0) && !region.isFlipY()){
        region.flip(false, true);
        walkingDown = false;
    }
    else if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y < 0) && region.isFlipY()){
        region.flip(false, true);
        walkingDown = true;
    }

    stateTimer = currentState == previousState ? stateTimer + dt : 0;
    previousState = currentState;

    return region;

}

public State getState(){
    if(b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y > 0 || b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y < 0){
        return State.WALKINGY;
    }
    else if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x > 0 || b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0)){
        return State.WALKINGX;
    }
    else{
        return State.STANDING;
    }
}

public void defineIsaac(){
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(32 / icsGame.PPM, 32 / icsGame.PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2Body = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(4 / icsGame.PPM);

    fdef.shape = shape;
    b2Body.createFixture(fdef);


}
}
```

This is my class for the head:

```
public class isaacHead extends Sprite {
public isaac.State currentState;
public isaac.State previousState;
public World world;
public Body b2Head;
private float stateTimer;
private TextureRegion isaacDefault;

public isaacHead(World world, playScreen screen){
    super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("isaac_body"));
    this.world = world;
    defineIsaacHead();
    isaacDefault = new TextureRegion(getTexture(), 0, 0, 32, 32);
    setBounds(0,0, 32 / icsGame.PPM, 32 / icsGame.PPM);
    setRegion(isaacDefault);

}

public void update(float dt){
    setPosition(b2Head.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2Head.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
}

public void defineIsaacHead(){
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(32 / icsGame.PPM, 32 / icsGame.PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2Head = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(6 / icsGame.PPM);

    fdef.shape = shape;
    b2Head.createFixture(fdef);
}

}
```

And this is my play screen class:

```
public class playScreen implements Screen {
private icsGame game;
private TextureAtlas atlas;

private OrthographicCamera gameCam;
private Viewport gamePort;
private Scenes.hud hud;

private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;

private isaac player;
private isaacHead head;

public playScreen(icsGame game) {
    atlas = new TextureAtlas("isaac.pack");

    this.game = game;
    gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new FitViewport(icsGame.V_WIDTH / icsGame.PPM,icsGame.V_HEIGHT / icsGame.PPM,gameCam);
    hud = new hud(game.batch);

    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("Level1.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / icsGame.PPM);
    gameCam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);

    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0), true);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    new b2WorldCreator(world, map);

    player = new isaac(world, this);
    head = new isaacHead(world, this);

}

public TextureAtlas getAtlas(){
    return atlas;
}

@Override
public void show() {
}

public void handleInput(float dt){
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(-1.5f,0f);
        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(1.5f,0f);
        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) == Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(0,1.5f);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y >= -2)
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(0,-1.5f);
        if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(-1.5f, -1.5f);
        }
        if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(1.5f, -1.5f);
        }
        if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(-1.5f, 1.5f);
        }
        if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(1.5f, 1.5f);
        }

}

public void update(float dt){
    handleInput(dt);

    world.step(1/60f,6,2);

    head.setPosition(player.b2Body.getPosition().x, player.b2Body.getPosition().y);

    player.update(dt);
    head.update(dt);

    gameCam.update();
    renderer.setView(gameCam);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();

    b2dr.render(world, gameCam.combined);

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    player.draw(game.batch);
    head.draw(game.batch);
    game.batch.end();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gamePort.update(width,height);

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();
    world.dispose();
    b2dr.dispose();
    hud.dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: Hello Friend, I would ask you again why are you using two pieces instead of only one (body + head together)? I believe it should be easier.Use aseprite to draw your character together in all conditions, UP animation, DOWN animation, etc and include all information in your pack. If you are following the MarioBros tutorial in youtube you will have all your answers. Hope it helps you. Cheers!!

Comment: I am actually making a binding of isaac remake and if you have seen that game the head actually can turn seperate from the body, this means I have to control the head with the arrow keys and the body with WASD. Since this post I have figured out that I can just send the b2body coordinates to the head class and then use those to attach the head to that body. My issue now is that I flip the textures going left and right like in the mariobros tutorial. The problem is when I flip a texture they like to move on the body so if I flip the body sprite right and flip the head sprite left it looks weird

Comment: By weird I mean misaligned, the head moves to the one side of the body and the body texture moves to the other side of the body it’s following. Any way to flip a texture with causing it to move to the opposite side of the body it’s following?

Comment: Yes, only one b2body to move the character it is how should be. Regarding the body and head(if they have to be attached with each other only the directions of movement should be flexible) in your Sprite Character Class include more conditions in your getState() method, getFrame(float dt) method and inside the Array<TextureRegion> frames you are adding the animations. So you create conditions for Running down and head  turns up, or Running down and the head turns left, or any other condition it would  be needed.

Comment: I am also creating a prototype of an RPG in libgdx and I am stuck in lots of points to make my game move on to the next step. Maybe we can be in touch and change experiences. Cheers!!